# How to convert an initial list to other that considers a sequence of min and max values for each element of the initial list?

Tags: python, pandas, list

## this is the list I have:

```
emissions=[30,50,20,70]
```

## this is the list I would like to get:

```
f=[0,30,30,80,80,100,100,160)

such as:
f=[]
f[1]=emissions[0]
f[2]=emissions[0]
f[3]=emissions[0]+emissions[1]
f[4]=emissions[0]+emissions[1]
f[5]=emissions[0]+emissions[1]+emissions[2]
f[6]=emissions[0]+emissions[1]+emissions[2]
f[7]=emissions[0]+emissions[1]+emissions[2]+emissions[3]
```

I believe the answer must consider some loop but I cant figure out how

Comment: What does this have to do with min/max? You're just adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.cumsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) with append `0`, [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with remove first and last repetead values by indexing if performance is important in large lists:

```
f = np.repeat(np.cumsum([0] + emissions), 2)[1:-1].tolist()
print (f)
[0, 30, 30, 80, 80, 100, 100, 170]
```

---

```
np.random.seed(123)
emissions = np.random.randint(100, size=1000).tolist()

In [107]: %%timeit 
     ...: np.repeat(np.cumsum([0] + emissions), 2)[1:-1].tolist()
     ...: 
     ...: 
149 µs ± 13.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [108]: %%timeit
     ...: cumsum = [0] + list(accumulate(emissions))
     ...: f = [x for pair in zip(cumsum, cumsum[1:]) for x in pair]
     ...: 
     ...: 
192 µs ± 14.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

A pure python approache would be to use [`accummulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) :

```
from itertools import accumulate

emissions = [30, 50, 20, 70]
cumsum = [0] + list(accumulate(emissions))
f = [x for pair in zip(cumsum, cumsum[1:]) for x in pair]

#[0, 30, 30, 80, 80, 100, 100, 170]
```

Answer (score 1):

With itertools:

```py
from itertools import accumulate, pairwise, chain

emissions = [30, 50, 20, 70]

f = [*chain(*pairwise([0, *accumulate(emissions)]))]

print(f)
```

Without:

```
s = 0
f = []
for e in emissions:
    f += s, (s := s + e)

print(f)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY9BCoMwEEX3OcVfJmpBWkqL4EnERZAEBzSRJFJ6lm7ctCfqprdprFUHPgwz_z_4j9dwD6010_Qcgz5cP2_tbA8KygVrOw_qB-sCZNOM_djJoDIMktyNfNyaVpJhTPXkPVnjUaI65RnOUceoS14zpudr8rPyZM3yKr6Tnco3hqiFiKnBkQlcC8Zmar5QaqatgwIZbP6CIY5GWsJn4B5FXJBCiR2ydPtXXKt-AQ)

Benchmark with random lists of length 1000 (like jezrael's):

```
100.69 ± 0.99 μs  Kelly1c
108.02 ± 1.19 μs  Kelly2
108.22 ± 1.72 μs  Kelly1b
109.11 ± 1.70 μs  jezrael
112.12 ± 1.23 μs  Kelly1
140.18 ± 1.35 μs  Timeless
```

Benchmark code ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=nVTNbtQwED5xyVPMrfY2DUkKBa20T8CVWxRF3uyYGhInih3obtUn4dIL3Llz4gF4gD4NYzvZH1qE1JWizDoz3zfzjWe-fu-39rrT9_ffRisv3j68ANX23WBBj22_BWFA95EcuhaUxcF2XWNmD1HXYzs2wmIMvVDDF2XIqq-F0iHCqhaVnd3Dv_DFWGGVsareg7UodEznG_wcRRuU8A6bZpsxbJUxqtOGLyOg34B2HDQUC8_DFjMxK9IYFoeUjgJLzstjzPV_QBOXYuXKFesG2TMY6mcyPAUeg9LKKtGsUn5Kkz9iMbCC1FuSrKIMZjcAEgjsvYNzcDtfAVEwA0sy4ByQH-crA917al2DxjwipHTN2DqutKTghnr6ZBH8BLW48Um5sl1eO9WzABRPgEW2LLn3uXEOznEq_CPuBoHNv_TVfTJgj8IysgIWC6kdAmLIORFcZGViO58xjyI56tqpF_oXzzdlNurJyOO9FvGcSxTtsZ0Ql3RLXtOT0_MmLSNXhXRVeIqQbT8obZk80Sdy8-EQbuWSWgencXe-ejc2hsmpZuv5LCwgwyvvb52_oXHCDfNwhSx5sczSsjzp6tmtGzdmSb2rJJd38OsH3PrZ82ev_NnvnwbOoshJKvSmaxODBJvll9zXVDku-vIBWZamU0rHShwC3csVTH404mqHK7JSfpB_vqZ_6-SrJKiwOlgj2vVGLOFYuNgtqjUODpLDS6DXIXSSIBF9j5okcY2eaSaZPFsMn3C78ury4w7Nescgk6rSosWq4mFRTvty3pt_AA)):

```py
import numpy as np
from itertools import accumulate, pairwise, chain
from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev

def Kelly1(emissions):
    return [*chain(*pairwise([0, *accumulate(emissions)]))]

def Kelly1b(emissions):
    return [*chain.from_iterable(pairwise([0, *accumulate(emissions)]))]

def Kelly1c(emissions):
    return [*chain.from_iterable(pairwise(accumulate(emissions, initial=0)))]

def Kelly2(emissions):
    s = 0
    f = []
    for e in emissions:
        f += s, (s := s + e)
    return f

def Timeless(emissions):
    cumsum = [0] + list(accumulate(emissions))
    return [x for pair in zip(cumsum, cumsum[1:]) for x in pair]

def jezrael(emissions):
    return np.repeat(np.cumsum([0] + emissions), 2)[1:-1].tolist()

funcs = Kelly1, Kelly1b, Kelly1c, Kelly2, Timeless, jezrael

emissions = [30, 50, 20, 70]
for f in funcs:
    print(f(emissions))

times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e6 for t in sorted(times[f])[:10]]
    return f'{mean(ts):6.2f} ± {stdev(ts):4.2f} μs '

np.random.seed(123)
for _ in range(100):
    emissions = np.random.randint(100, size=1000).tolist()
    for f in funcs:
        t = timeit(lambda: f(emissions), number=100) / 100
        times[f].append(t)

for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)
```